# How to find the place where the iOS code crashes using Firebase ? (when you can't reproduce the bug)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, debugging, crash

I'm using Firebase to get information about crashes of users of my application. Most of the crashes has no any useful information about code or place where it happens. All stack-trace and threads shows "Missing" text. Also I can't reproduce these crashes at my PC.

That crash is on Mac OS application, not iOS. My point of view is to look at that doc, (see "Build Your App With Symbol Information"). But may be on Mac OS apps that feature is not available.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building_your_app_to_include_debugging_information

What can I do to find the place it crashes ? See attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Yes, well, you need to symbolicate.

Comment: But why some crashes are symbolicated and some not ?